# Problema de java con espacios en blanco

Tags: java

El ejercicio completo es solicita el nombre y apellido de una persona. Sin embargo no puede haber más de un espacio separándolos.
Agradecería mucho a la persona que pueda ayudarme.
El código q hice es este:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Ejercicio_6 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String nombre="",apellido;
        String n;
        int longitud;

        Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Ingrese su nombre: ");
        nombre = stdIn.nextLine();
        longitud=nombre.length();
        for(int i=0;i<=longitud;i++) {
            if (nombre.charAt(i)==' ') {
                System.out.println("No se solicitó un espacio de más."
                        + "\n El espacio será eliminado.");
                nombre=nombre.substring(0,longitud-1);
                System.out.println("Ingrese su apellido: ");
                apellido = stdIn.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Usted es: "+nombre+
                        " "+apellido);


            }


        }


    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

`apellido = apellido.replaceAll("  "," ");`
Utiliza replaceAll con expresiones regulares(Regex). Espero que te sirva, saludos

Answer (score 0):

aqui te dejo una posible solucion

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String nombre = "", apellido;
        String n;
        int longitud;
        Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);
        int contador = 0;
        while (contador < 1) {
            System.out.println("Ingrese su nombre y apellido ");
            nombre = stdIn.nextLine();
            longitud = nombre.length();

            for (int i = 0; i <= longitud-1; i++) {
                if (nombre.charAt(i) == ' ') {
                    contador++;
                    if (contador > 1) {
                        contador =0;
                    }else{
                        System.err.println("  Enter para continuar ");
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
```